# python mutagen, mp4 file, how to use ‘rtng’ – Content Rating tag?

Tags: python, mp4, mutagen

On Windows, when you look at "Details" tab for an mp4 file, there is a "Parental rating" field which seems to be free text. I am trying to set that to "PG", "R", etc. for my movies.

The mutagen python module has a "rtng" tag, described as Content Rating, with an integer value. I am assuming these two attributes are related, and somehow there is a mapping from integer to an actual rating?

If that's true, I tried this:

```
from mutagen.mp4 import MP4
f = 'myfile.mp4'
mp4_video_tags = MP4(f)
mp4_video_tags['\xa9nam'] = 'My Title is long'
mp4_video_tags['\xa9gen'] = 'My Genre1; My Genre2'
mp4_video_tags['\xa9day'] = '1919'
mp4_video_tags['\xa9cmt'] = 'My Comments are very long'
mp4_video_tags['rtng'] = 1
mp4_video_tags.save()
print(mutagen.File(f))
```

Everything works, except "mp4_video_tags['rtng'] = 1". I get

```
mutagen.mp4.MP4MetadataValueError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

When I tried quoting the '1':

```
mp4_video_tags['rtng'] = '1'
```

I get another error:

```
mutagen.mp4.MP4MetadataValueError: value out of range: '1'
```

So my questions are

1. Is the Parental rating attribute on the file set through 'rtng'?
2. How to set 'rtng' correctly?
3. What are the integer values for G, PG, PG13, R, etc?

Answer (score 2):

The `rtng` tag is used to denote the Parental Advisory attributes. It is mainly used by mp3 files to tag *Explicit* and *Clean* music types.

`rtng = 2` would evaluate to *Clean*
`rtng = 4` would evaluate to *Explicit*
`rtng = 0` would evaluate to *None*

Anything other than 0,2 and 4, mutagen evaluates that to *Explicit*

**EDIT**
Its strange that that it requires a `list` rather that an `int`
And when you do give it a `list` it then works fine but you have multiple ratings separated by `/`which is really strange. This is a problem to it in this respect.

For example when you give it a list = `[0,2,4]` it sets Rating tag to `None / Explicit / Clean`

Currently there doesn't seem to be a tag supported by mutagen that would contain Content Rating for Movies like PG, PG-13,R, etc

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late for the party, but someone else can help. Answering your questions:

1. Yes, parental rating attribute on file is set via 'rtng'.
2. The correct way to configure is by putting an integer inside a list:
   `mp4_video_tags['rtng'] = [0]` to None.
   `mp4_video_tags['rtng'] = [2]` to Clean.
   `mp4_video_tags['rtng'] = [4]` to Explicit.
3. As you answered above, there currently does not appear to be a mutagens compliant
   tag that contains content rating for movies.